# Why does this zig program fail to compile due to "expected error union type, found 'error:124:18'"?

Tags: zig

```
test "error union if" {
    var ent_num: error{UnknownEntity}!u32 = error.UnknownEntity;
    if (ent_num) |entity| {
        try expect(@TypeOf(entity) == u32);
        try expect(entity == 5);
    } else |err| {
        _ = err catch |err1| { // compiles fine when this block is removed
            std.debug.print("{s}", .{err1});
        };
        std.debug.print("{s}", .{err});
    }
}
```

```
./main.zig:125:5: error: expected error union type, found 'error:124:18'
    if (ent_num) |entity| {
    ^
./main.zig:129:17: note: referenced here
        _ = err catch |err1| {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `error:124:18` refers to the `error{UnknownEntity}` because it's
   anonymous. so prints the definition address.
2. the `if (my_var) |v| ...` syntax can only be used for optional
   types. for *Error unions* you must use `try` or `catch`.
3. `try` and `catch` can't be used for *Error Set*

your code would be this:

```rs
const std = @import("std");
const expect = std.testing.expect;

test "error union if" {
    var ent_num: error{UnknownEntity}!u32 = error.UnknownEntity;
    const entity: u32 = ent_num catch |err| {
        std.debug.print("{s}", .{err});
        return;
    };

    try expect(@TypeOf(entity) == u32);
    try expect(entity == 5);
}
```

reading the programs or libraries is very useful for learning a new language. gl

Comment: Thanks Ali, your explanation makes sense. One follow up question - why `if (ent_num) |entity| {` shows up in the compile error? Afaik that line is correct, ent_num is of type error union.

Comment: Another question, you mentioned "try and catch can only be used for Error Union, not Error Set", why does `_ = err catch {};` works instead? The example is in https://ziglearn.org/chapter-1/#payload-captures, you can find it by searching for `_ = err catch {};`.

Comment: sorry my bad. you can use `if`, `else` for error unions but can't understand how's `_ = error catch {}` works with error set. but still sure it's wrong.

Comment: Nit: I think the `err` in `err catch {};` is of type error, not error set.

Comment: Maybe `expr catch {}` without capture just works with any expression that evaluates to error value.

Comment: `_ = err catch {}` is odd; at this point in the program (inside the `else |err| {}` block) you already know `err` is an error, so you wouldn't need to apply the `catch` operator, which is supposed to extract the error value from an error union.